# PHP - Query by multiple value in one table?

Tags: php, sql

I have:

```
+--+----+-----------+
|id|key |value      |
+--+----+-----------+
|1 |date|01-Jan-2014|
+--+----+-----------+
|2 |date|02-Jam-2014|
+--+----+-----------+
|3 |date|01-Feb-2014|
+--+----+-----------+
|4 |date|01-Mar-2014|
+--+----+-----------+
```

And I want to get data where date is from 01-Feb-2014 to 01-Marc-2014

Result like:

```
+--+----+-----------+
|id|key |value      |
+--+----+-----------+
|3 |date|01-Feb-2014|
+--+----+-----------+
|4 |date|01-Mar-2014|
+--+----+-----------+
```

Comment: please tell me those are not the real db date values, if so you should start by changing the db structure to use one of the date field types

Comment: which datatype value field have?

Comment: The 2nd of *Jam* a tasty day

Answer (score 1):

MySQL:

```
SELECT id, key, value FROM table WHERE value BETWEEN '01-Feb-2014' to '01-March-2014'
```

Comment: You're assuming that the OP has used MySQL date fields. This won't work if he hasn't.

Comment: why `SELECT date`? OP wants `id`, `key` and `value`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:
i am assuming that value is date time type data.

```
 SELECT *
    FROM `table_name`
    WHERE (value BETWEEN ('2014-02-01 00:00:00' ,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AND ('2014-03-01 00:00:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'))
```

Comment: You're assuming that the OP has used MySQL date fields. This won't work if he hasn't.